# Powershell regex to grab data between second set of double quotes

Tags: regex, powershell

I have a dataset like the below, I've been trying to use split to get the second column of data.  Can this be done with a regex?  I just need the data in the second column, the unc paths.

```
"\app\DATA\8161ST1\201901\20190111\2562233\" "\\server\i\Run\client\AHFC\201901\app\DATA\8161ST1\201901\20190111\2562233\*.*"
"\app\DATA\8161ST1\201901\20190111\2562234\" "\\server\i\Run\client\AHFC\201901\app\DATA\8161ST1\201901\20190111\2562234\*.*"
"\app\DATA\8161ST1\201901\20190111\2562235\" "\\server\i\Run\client\AHFC\201901\app\DATA\8161ST1\201901\20190111\2562235\*.*"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A conceptually simple solution:

```
# Array of input lines, such as would be returned by Get-Content
$lines = @' 
"\app\DATA\8161ST1\201901\20190111\2562233\" "\\server\i\Run\client\AHFC\201901\app\DATA\8161ST1\201901\20190111\2562233\*.*"
"\app\DATA\8161ST1\201901\20190111\2562234\" "\\server\i\Run\client\AHFC\201901\app\DATA\8161ST1\201901\20190111\2562234\*.*"
"\app\DATA\8161ST1\201901\20190111\2562235\" "\\server\i\Run\client\AHFC\201901\app\DATA\8161ST1\201901\20190111\2562235\*.*"
'@ -split [Environment]::NewLine

# Extract the content of the last "..."-enclosed token from each line.
$lines | ForEach-Object { ($_ -split '"')[-2] }
```

The above yields:

```
\\server\i\Run\client\AHFC\201901\app\DATA\8161ST1\201901\20190111\2562233\*.*
\\server\i\Run\client\AHFC\201901\app\DATA\8161ST1\201901\20190111\2562234\*.*
\\server\i\Run\client\AHFC\201901\app\DATA\8161ST1\201901\20190111\2562235\*.*
```

Comment: Or to preserve the quotes `$lines | ForEach-Object { ($_ -split ' (?=")')[-1] }`